# else inside if condition not checking in android

Tags: android, if-statement

Hi in the below code else inside if condition inside is not checking if the username and password matches with Admin user found directly it's checking only if after that else if was checking.But inside else under the if condition was not going.

**java**

```
else{

        queryString = "username=" + username + "&password="
                + password ;
        String usertype = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("login",queryString);
        System.out.print(usertype);

        if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin user Found")){

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run(){

                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Sucess",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           

               }
        });

        Intent in=new Intent(Login.this, Reports.class);
        startActivity(in);

    }


    else if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("No User Found")){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

             public void run() {     

                 tv2.setText("InValid UserName and Password");

             }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Between the horrible indentation and the large amount of code it's hard to tell to *which* `else` you're referring. In fact, the only ones I see aren't inside `if`s. Do you really need to show us the whole class?

Comment: I have only one else in that one is if condition and another one is else if. But suppose username name password matches with admin users means just move to one activity.otherwise it will stay in same activity

Comment: The code you've posted contains *two* `else`s (that aren't `else if`s), and your title and question both say ‘*else inside if*’. Could you make up your mind? And could you remove all the unrelated code from the question? And could you *please* indent your code?

Comment: @Biffen now you can check it out

Comment: There's still no ‘*else inside if*’ as the question suggests, and the indentation is still horrible, so no, I'd rather not ‘*check it out*’. Did you try debugging it? At least let us know whether and what `System.out.print(usertype);` prints.

Comment: Exactly like that? No extra whitespace? (What do you get for `System.out.print("[[[" + usertype + "]]]");`?) And are you *sure* it doesn't enter the `if` block? What do you see when you run it through a debugger?

Comment: yes it coming out of the else

Comment: Where did `]]]` go? Is it perhaps on the next line?

Comment: @Biffen that one is not printed

Comment: If `System.out.print("[[[" + usertype + "]]]");` doesn't print `]]]` then something is *very* broken. What I'm after is that `usertype` has some trailing whitespace, e.g. a newline, so while it may *look* like one thing to human eyes it is in fact somewhat different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using `else` instead of `else if` ???
The problem cant be with java,
Debug the app and check value of your variable `userType` it will be different.
If you cant debug you can show toast to check its value.

```
   if (!isInternetPresent) {
        showAlertDialog(Login.this, "No Internet Connection",
                "You don't have internet connection.", true);

        return;


    }
    //// If Condition Finishes


    String username = usname.getText().toString();
    String password = pword.getText().toString();

    // String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);


    if (username.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER USERNAME",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    //// If Condition Finishes


    if (password.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER PASSWORD",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    //// If Condition Finishes

    else if (!CheckUsername(username) && !CheckPassword(password)){
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER VALID USERNAME & PASSWORD",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //// Else If Condition Finishes

    else{
        queryString = "username=" + username + "&password="
                + password ;
        String usertype = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("login",queryString);
        System.out.print(usertype);

        if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin user Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Sucess",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });


            Intent in=new Intent(Login.this, Reports.class);
            startActivity(in);

        }
        //// If Condition Finishes



        //// I Suppose this is the else if you are talking about
        else if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("No User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    tv2.setText("InValid UserName and Password");

                }

            });
        }
        //// Else If Condition Finishes

    }
    //// Else Condition Finishes
```

I hope it helps.
Good Luck :)

Comment: @care567 what is not working, i proposed you 2 solutions. Try ELSE and debug VALUE, whats the VALUE?

Comment: http://rushdainfotech.in/Mobile_VcareHospital/login.php?username=vcadmin&password=vcadmin121&user_type=Admin this is my server url link

Comment: @care567 maybe your runOnUiThread or tv2.setText is not working, try showing a toast before that in your else if and i think it will work...

Comment: your right runOnUiThread it's not working.but as well as inside if condition also not working above the if condition working

Comment: you should add @Override notation above your public void run()

Comment: After adding Override notation then also not working

Comment: try to printing the length of the usertype like this System.out.print(usertype.length()); nothing was printing

Comment: Then what i have to use

Comment: got it was the problem equalIgnore case is not working when try to changing to startwith working perfect with runUiThread

Comment: you can also use .contains it would be better

Answer (score 0):

if your the Following if block is not working

**

> if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin user Found")){

**

Then its mean that your "usertype" is not equal to "Admin user Found".

Simple as it seems